# Postgres table didn't set autoincrement on primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

In Rails, My Membership model migration looks like this:

```
class CreateMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :memberships do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :organization_id
      t.integer :membership_type_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and my User model migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

To me, these look pretty much the same. However, when I look at the tables in `psql` I see this:

```
cd_dev=# \d memberships
                  Table "public.memberships"
       Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id                 | integer                     | not null
```

and

```
cd_dev=# \d users
                                       Table "public.users"
    Column     |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
---------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
```

In other words, the id field of `memberships` table is not automatically being assigned. In Rails console, when I attempt to create a new Membership by simply doing `Membership.create(user_id: 1, organization_id: 1)` it fails saying:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

I could probably google a way to make the `id` field work correctly on `memberships`, but what I don't understand is how this happened. Is there something I should know about Rails/Postgres? I don't remember if I used rails generators or manually typed out the migration for each of these models.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't normal. Are you sure you didn't fiddle with the database manually? try

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it's not normal. The problem existed in my development AND production database on heroku. I did fiddle with the db manually at one point a long time ago but I'm 99% sure my fiddling was on an entirely different table. I will try creating a new db in dev and running migrations. 

PS, I didn't know you could chain rake commands like that?

Comment: Yeah you can, it's a nice trick - you don't have to wait for rake to load up the rails environment each time, it will do all 3 in one go.